# Execution of Google Dataform workflow gives error access denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataform, google-dataform

I tried to manually execute a Google Dataform workflow, but it gives me the following error:

> Access Denied: Project 6398708432: User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project 6398708432.

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The service account processing the workflow needs the following roles to be able to execute the Google Dataform workflow:

- Bigquery Job User
- Bigquery User
- Bigquery data editor

In IAM of your project add these roles to the service account:
service-YOUR_PROJECT_ID@gcp-sa-dataform.iam.gserviceaccount.com

See also more explanation here:
https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/quickstart#grant-access-bigquery

[image: iam roles service account for using dataform]